# Axis2 with JSON Support

Tags: java, json, apache-axis

I have an Axis2 web service that's already deployed, and which communicates with clients using SOAP. There's a new requirement now to enable REST calls by sending JSON requests and receiving JSON formatted responses.

Following this small tutorial: http://code.google.com/p/jsonp-support-for-axis2/wiki/OneStopPage

I was able to configure my Axis 2 web service correctly. Using my browser, I used the following URL to return a Student object:

```
http://localhost:8181/Axis2Json/services/StudentService/getStudent?response=application/json&value=3
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
{"return":{"@type":"ax21:Student","age":25,"firstName":"Mouhammed","lastName":"Soueidane"}}
```

The problem is that the returned JSON, doesn't look like a standard JSON representation (Not even in badgerfish format). So for instance, if I want to call a method called "setStudent" which takes in a Student object, I really have no clue of the JSON string that I need to pass to it.

I tried so many stuff, most of which resulted in a casting exception `(java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONObject)`

Does anyone have an idea about how to allow an Axis 2 web service to use both SOAP and JSON, based on the content type of the client?

Comment: Did you find an answer for this

Comment: This question is too old for me to remember. One thing is for sure: For all intents and purposes, I now use Jersey to expose RESTful web services. As far as I can remmeber, Axis 2 had a terrible support for REST.